# Aligning two content causes content to shrink right away

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align two content next to each other in a way when the broswer minimizes, the content will not move/shrink/ until the screen touchees the content. I tried to replicated aligning two content close to each other but failed. Whenever the browser shrinks, the image shrinks right away instead of shrinking when the window touches the content. Below is the code I am using,

```
<div class="prod_section">
      <div class="border col-md-6">
         <img src="img/land_prod_one.jpg" class="word">
         <h2>content1</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="border col-md-6">
         <img src="img/land_prod_two.jpg" class="word">
         <h2>content2</h2>
   </div>
</div>



.prod_section{
  margin: auto;
    width: 60%;
    padding: 10px;

    padding-top:220px;
}

.word{
    max-width:100%;
}
```

Below is an image displaying how I am trying to make the content look. This is in the website called Obey Clothing. If anyone can help out, it would greatly be appreciated. Thank you for your time.

[image: Image displays how I am trying to align content]

Comment: That's happening because `.prod_section` has `width: 60%`, which is a relative width to the screen size. So as the screen shrinks, that element will shrink, and the images inside of it will shrink, too. One way around it is to use a fixed width or `width: 100%`. Your actual solution probably depends on the context of the rest of the page. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GEZQGL

Answer (score 0):

1st, the width of the container is set to 60%, which cause your content to shrink sometime (depend on the size of the img)

2nd, you might want to add `clearfix` to your container check the two example below in full-page to see the difference.

```css
.prod_section {
  margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-top: 220px;
  background: green;
}

.word {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="prod_section">
  <div class="border col-md-6">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x350" class="word">
    <h2>content1</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="border col-md-6">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x350" class="word">
    <h2>content2</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Solution:

```css
.prod_section {
  margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-top: 220px;
  background: green;
}

.word {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.clearfix:after {
   content: " ";
   visibility: hidden;
   display: block;
   height: 0;
   clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="prod_section clearfix">
  <div class="border col-md-6">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x350" class="word">
    <h2>content1</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="border col-md-6">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x350" class="word">
    <h2>content2</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I minimize the browser window, the content wrapper/.prod_section still shrinks before the window touches the green background. Both of the results im getting are the same. Is it possible for the content to minimize right when the content touches the window? Like the way performed in this site https://obeyclothing.com/?gclid=CLafq_7kpNQCFQMLaQodB9wOOg

Comment: update- I added a width of 1200px (fixed width, and the content was able to not shrink when minimizing before the screen touches the image. Then I added @media querie of 100%, once the window touches the content at a certain screen size, the browser turn off width:1200px, and uses width: 100%)

Comment: @ricky just to you know Bootstrap `md` is 992px. `.col-md-$ Medium Devices Desktops 992px and Up` good luck coding